# Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'IValueResolver<Entity, MyDto, object>' because it is not a delegate type

Tags: c#, automapper, .net-6.0

I am trying to define this simple mapping in my profile

```
CreateMap<CompanyClient, MyDto>() 
.ForMember(
    dto => dto.PaymentTerms,
    opt => opt.MapFrom(companyClient => companyClient.Company.PaymentTerms != null
        ? companyClient.Company.PaymentTerms.Value
        : null))
```

But I'm getting this stupid error message:

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'IValueResolver<CompanyClient, MyDto, object>' because it is not a delegate type

What exacly is the problem here? I have used plenty of ternary operators elsewhere in my code, but for some reason this nullable `SmartEnum` case has some kind of problem

entity:

```
public sealed class CompanyClient
{
    ...
    Public PaymentTerm? PaymentTerms { get; private set; }
    ...
}
```

dto:

```
public sealed record MyDto
{
    ...
    Public int? PaymentTerms { get; private init; }
    ...
}
```

PaymentTerm.cs is just a simple [SmartEnum](https://github.com/ardalis/SmartEnum)

Note that it does not give any compiler errors when I write it like this:

```
.ForMember(
    dto => dto.PaymentTerms,
    opt => opt.MapFrom(companyClient => companyClient.Company.PaymentTerms ?? null))
```

or

```
.ForMember(
    dto => dto.PaymentTerms,
    opt => opt.MapFrom(companyClient => companyClient.Company.PaymentTerms))
```

What is the problem?

Comment: is 'init' a typo?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found that we can get rid of this stupid message by just casting the non-null result to the output type.

So where

```
.ForMember(
    dst => dst.VisitReportFileId,
    opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.VisitReportFile == null 
        ? null 
        : src.VisitReportFile.Id.Key));
```

Gives me a

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'IValueResolver<Activity, ActivityDTO, object>' because it is not a delegate type

I can fix it by casting the "else" result to `Guid?`:

```
.ForMember(
    dst => dst.VisitReportFileId,
    opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.VisitReportFile == null 
        ? null 
        : (Guid?)src.VisitReportFile.Id.Key));
```

Comment: Works also if you cast null to (Guid?) (at least if worked for me where I had DateTimeOffset?)

Comment: Worked for me !

Answer (score 2):

The reason for your error is that the conditional operator (`c ? t : f`) takes precedence over the lambda declaration (`=>`).
[source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/#operator-precedence)

Wrapping the conditional operator in `{}` brackets should solve your problem:

```cs
CreateMap<CompanyClient, MyDto>() 
.ForMember(
    dto => dto.PaymentTerms,
    opt => opt.MapFrom(companyClient => 
    {
        companyClient.Company.PaymentTerms != null
            ? companyClient.Company.PaymentTerms.Value
            : null
    }))
```

Comment: Thanks Martijn. Any idea what this would be happening for nullable SmartEnum, but not for other nullable types?

Answer (score 0):

If someone has this error and the answers above do not help, try the following.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60379426/13434418

Preview (Conditional mapping with different source types)

```
//Cannot convert lambda expression to type
x.MapFrom(src => src.CommunityId.HasValue ? src.Community : src.Account)
//OK
x.MapFrom(src => src.CommunityId.HasValue ? (object)src.Community : src.Account)
```

Comment: The C# compiler is failing to infer the type of the `?:` expression, and pick the correct method from the group at the same time. Here's a similar test case; https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQMwAICWA7ALgUwCcAzAQwGN90BJAJXwGcB7AGwDciAeANQD4BvZAF9kadLHQBhdIKTp54jFAAs4gKy5MTbD14AKOo1YdCu9G1IsArvgCUshehFyFYles3bdeqGrMXrOwcFZ0c3VQBZPVsZZEcwjS1sPWiAXl50XEIbdAB+dGwrFhZ0EHQ4WwBuOPj5X09ktIysnPzgfDIi3D0cXBiyiuqXeWchIA== The handling of `?:` types did change in C# 9.